# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm creating an **Electron app with react js**, after building the solution "npm run build" then open the desktop app, it shows nothing just a white page. and then open the console these warnings in the picture appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Was a wrong URL in `**Window.loadURL**`,
and about the warning of sourceMap it's a browser issue and will not affect your code running.